# Sessions not working in my PHP form

Tags: php, session

I did this so that I could use the variable Semester somewhere else in the page

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
$semester = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['semester']) ;

$_SESSION['semester'] = $semester;
?>
```

and it is not working somewhere else on the page. So, what did I do wrong?

Comment: did you forget the `<?php`? what is $semeters?

Comment: would it not be easier storing the value of semester in a database?

Comment: The *somewhere else on the page* code is missing in your question.

Comment: you really need to add more detail.  For starters, what do you mean by "it's not working"?  Also, show the code where it isn't working, etc.

Comment: i think you dont have an open db conenction , mysql_real_escape_string  need a connection.

Comment: Semester is a variable i'll be using to complete a student score entry application
@Liam Allan... Yes i do have it in a database along with the school session(academic year) and course name, which will be used to enter the second part of the form, for student score entry application.

Thanks.

Comment: People change the OP too much, assuming things that are there that might not be.

Comment: i have other variables which i've not written out, am doing a student score computation, according to the semester, session(academic year), and course code. This variables will be used in the in the second part of the form entry where the lecturer enters the score, which must be in the right semester, session and course name. So thats why i want to use the PHP SESSIONS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you do `session_start();` at the top of your script? that's usually the issue in problems like this.  it took me a while to learn that one when I started doing session stuff :)